# Let X=C with the usual metric and A={(x,y):y=sin1x,0<x≤1}. Show that cl(A)=A∪{(0,y):−1≤y≤1}.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let X=$\mathbb{C}$ with the usual metric and A=$\{(x,y):y=\sin\frac{1}{x},0< x \leq 1\}$. Show that $\text{cl}(A)=A \cup \{(0,y):−1 \leq y \leq 1\}$.

Hint: Each open ball centred at $(0,y)$, $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ has non-empty intersection with $A$. It may be seen that every point outside $ A \cup \{(0,y):-1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ is the centre of a ball having an empty intersection with $A$.

How do we use the hint to prove the following question?

Comment: What is C here?

Comment: Your post is hard to read and various things should be fixed. The first paragraph of post seems to have been cut off. Also, please typeset the mathematics in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: C is complex numbers.